# To devote vs. dedicate yourself: which works better for being studious?

Tags: word-choice

In regards to studiousness, if I were to advise students to focus on their studies, should I say:

> Just dedicate yourself.

or rather

> Just devote yourself.

Am I right to feel that *devote yourself* sounds a bit too religious?

Comment: *Devote* is not primarily religious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking for subjective judgments, which is fine, but you'll get no definitive answer to this question. It's strictly a matter of personal preference: "What I like is what you should say".

To answer your real question:

No, "[devotion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopelessly_Devoted_to_You)" is not too "religious":